# Edit Record using Partial View, JQuery and Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a table on which there's an `Edit` button for every record at the last column.

My goal is to have an editable form on a modal for the record on which the user pressed the `Edit` button.

In order to accomplish that, I've created a Partial View which i want to be loaded on the modal, but after tons of tries, i cannot get it working. The JS created to compose the partial view URL and loading into the modal seems to have no effect and it's raising the following error:

> VM364 ESa31501901:361 Uncaught ReferenceError: ESa31501901 is not
>   defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

**Note:** ESa31501901 is the first parameter passed into the JS function.

This is my intention:

a) `Edit()` : This method will return all records.

b) `EditClientFeature(string ClientID, string WorkProcessID)`: This method will return a partial view containing the record of a particular client. This method is called when we start editing a client record. The client record is displayed in modal (popup).

c) `EditClientFeature(ClientFeatureViewModel model)`: This method will update the client record.

**ClientFeature ViewModel**

```
public class ClientFeatureViewModel
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string WorkProcessID { get; set; }
    public int? Certification { get; set; }
    public bool? TrackingActive { get; set; }
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
    public string ContractNo { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
[...]

<tbody>
@foreach (var feature in Model.ClientFeatures)
{
 <tr>
     <td style="text-align:center"><strong>@feature.WorkProcessId</strong>/td>
     <td style="text-align:center">@feature.Certificate</td>
     <td style="text-align:center">@feature.TrackingActive</td>
     <td style="text-align:center">@feature.ClientCode</td>
     <td style="text-align:center">@feature.ContractNo</td>
     <td style="text-align:center">@feature.ProductCode</td>
     <td>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="EditCF(@Model.Piva, @feature.WorkProcessId)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a>                                                                                                                                                                
    </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>

[...]

    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalClientFeatures">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBodyDiv">

                  <!-- Here's where i want to show the partial view-->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

[...]

<script>    
        function EditCF(ClientID, WorkProcessID) {

            var url = "/Admin/EditClientFeature?ClientID=" + ClientID + "?WorkProcessID=" + WorkProcessID;

            $("#ModalBodyDiv").load(url, function () {
                $("#ModalClientFeatures").modal("show");

            })

        }
</script>
```

**ClientFeaturepartialView.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Models.ClientFeatureViewModel

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<form id="myForm">

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClientFeatureViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClientID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkProcessID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkProcessID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WorkProcessID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Certification, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Certification, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Certification, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TrackingActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrackingActive)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TrackingActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContractNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContractNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContractNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                    <span>Update</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult EditClientFeature(string ClientID, string WorkProcessID)
    {
        PMEntities db = new EntityConn().Db;

        ClientFeatures ClientFeature = db.ClientFeatures.Where(cf => cf.ClientId == ClientID && cf.WorkProcessId == WorkProcessID).SingleOrDefault();

        if (ClientFeature != null) {

            ClientFeatureViewModel model = new ClientFeatureViewModel
            {
                ClientID = ClientFeature.ClientId,
                WorkProcessID = ClientFeature.WorkProcessId,
                Certification = ClientFeature.Certificate,
                TrackingActive = ClientFeature.TrackingActive,
                ClientCode = ClientFeature.ClientCode,
                ContractNo = ClientFeature.ContractNo,
                ProductCode = ClientFeature.ProductCode,

            };

            return PartialView("ClientFeaturePartialView", model);
        }
        else { return View("Error"); }      

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditClientFeature(ClientFeatureViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            PMEntities db = new EntityConn().Db;

            if (model.ClientID != null)
            {
                //update
                ClientFeatures ClientFeature = db.ClientFeatures.Where(cf => cf.ClientId == model.ClientID && cf.WorkProcessId == model.WorkProcessID).SingleOrDefault();

                ClientFeature.Certificate = model.Certification;
                ClientFeature.ClientCode = model.ClientCode;
                ClientFeature.ContractNo = model.ContractNo;
                ClientFeature.ProductCode = model.ProductCode;
                ClientFeature.TrackingActive = model.TrackingActive;

                db.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `onclick` function parameter value is treated as a variable, not a string.

**Solution 1:**

Try below to pass as string: (Not tested though!)

```
onclick="EditCF(\'' + @Model.Piva + '\', \'' + @feature.WorkProcessId+ '\')"
```

**Solution 2:**

It's best to Attach a `click` handler after adding a class for your link. And use `HTML5` [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) for storing your value client side.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success editClient" data-ClientID="@Model.Piva" data-WorkProcessId="@feature.WorkProcessId"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a> 


$('.editClient).on('click', function() {
    var clientID = $(this).data('ClientID');
    var workProcessId = $(this).data('WorkProcessId');

    var url = "/Admin/EditClientFeature?ClientID=" + clientID 
    + "?WorkProcessID=" + workProcessID;

    $("#ModalBodyDiv").load(url, function () {

      $("#ModalClientFeatures").modal("show");

    })

});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877617/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-onclick-when-using-character-strings)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!. I've tried and it's working. The modal is shown with the content of the partial view. But there is a problem. The formed url is correct (I've checked showing an `alert(url);` before loading the modal), but parameters passed into the controller method are wrong. ClientID comes with `"ESa31501901?WorkProcessID=BCC_BN_FR"` value and WorkProcessID comes with `null`. Do you know why?

Comment: @equisde , Did you try Solution 1 ?

Comment: Nope! I went directly to the option that I thought was more correct  :-D
Let me try and i'll revert with the result. Thanks!

Comment: @equisde ok , By the way , If the url is correct then it should pass correct values to your `Action Method`. Kindly check parameters name , it should match.

Comment: Unafortunately the console is showing this JS error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when clicking button in the 1st option. :(

Checking back the 2nd option, parameters name seems to be correct at my Action method. In fact `ClientID` is being received, but it's containing the right-side part of the url, starting from the `=` symbol. ClientID Content: `ClientID + "?WorkProcessID=" + WorkProcessID;`

Comment: I think the url should be: `var url = "/Admin/EditClientFeature/" + clientID 
    + "/" + workProcessID;`

Comment: Finallly i get it working. As you said url was being wrong formed. Solved with `var url = "/Admin/EditClientFeature?ClientID=" + ClientID + "&WorkProcessID=" + WorkProcessID;`. Thanks for all!

Comment: Meanwhile you can double check if your `Action Method` works properly, Run the application, In Browser tab. Enter htttp://localhist:0000/Admin/EditClientFeature/ESa31501901/BCC_BN_FR , Check wether you are receiving the value.